# Convert Smart Device Dll to ActiveX control for Windows Mobile

Tags: com, windows-mobile, compact-framework, activex

I am using C# and Visual Studio 2008.

I have a class that will turn on the scanner of my Windows Mobile Device and then will capture the read of the scanner when pressed. It will also shut down appropriately and cleanly. I am using a vendor provided SDK to do a lot of the heavy lifting.

I have this working correctly in a Mobile App, but I also need the dll to be able to be called via COM/ActiveX from a web site. I have been going around and around about how to do this. I've bounced between various settings and project types. I've tried converting it over to C++ and ATL. But so far nothing works.

I get conflicting information depending upon where I look. I need help. Can only C++ do this? Is there something I'm missing? I can't be the only person needing to do this. How can I do this?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You need to scan barcodes in a web application running in Windows Mobile IE ?

Comment: Yes, the mobile device has a built in scanner. The maker of the device provides a handy .NET SDK for the scanner and other features of the phone. 

My client has an existing web site where they want to be able to use the scanner to input the scanned data into a text box in the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create ActiveX/COM components in managed code with the Compact Framework.  There is not EE Hosting support, so it simply cannot be done.  You will have to write this in C++ (not managed C++, but old-fashioned native).

As a side note that is sometimes overlooked on COM controls, you also have to implement [IObjectSafety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768224(VS.85).aspx) for the control to work in a browser.